# Fetching multiple API requests with React Native

Tags: react-native, promise, react-router, fetch-api

Here is an outline of my code (sparing some details). Basically I just want to make two similar API requests when I click a button, then have a function that works with the results of both the requests, but I cannot figure it out.

```
class myClass extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.API_KEY_ONE = ‘firstapikey’
        this.API_KEY_TWO = ‘secondapikey’
        this.state = {
           city: 'undefined',
           state: 'undefined'
        }
      }

callOne() {
    this.REQUEST_URL = 'https://api.wunderground.com/api/' + this.API_KEY_ONE +    '/geolookup/conditions/astronomy/forecast/q/.json';

    fetch(this.REQUEST_URL).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseData)  => {

       this.setState({
        city: responseData.location.city
        });

    }).done();
}

 callTwo() {
      this.REQUEST_URL = 'https://api.DifferentSite.com/api/' + this.API_KEY_TWO +  '/geolookup/conditions/astronomy/forecast/q/.json';

      fetch(this.REQUEST_URL).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseData) => {

         this.setState({
        state: responseData.location.state
         });

     }).done();
}

// where to put this? when both requests finish, pass both to new component

this.props.navigator.push({
    title: 'Forecast',
    component: Forecast,
    passProps: {city: this.state.city, state: this.state.state}
  });


getForecast() {
     this.callOne();
     this.callTwo();
}

<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.getForecast()} />
```

Answer (score 4):

You can continue with `.then()` so it should be something like this:

```
callBoth(){
    var request_1_url = 'https://api.wunderground.com/api/' + this.API_KEY_ONE +    '/geolookup/conditions/astronomy/forecast/q/.json';
    var request_2_url = 'https://api.DifferentSite.com/api/' + this.API_KEY_TWO +  '/geolookup/conditions/astronomy/forecast/q/.json';

    fetch(request_1_url).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseData)  => {
        this.setState({
            city: responseData.location.city
        });
    }).then(()=>{
        fetch(request_2_url).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseData) => {
         this.setState({
            state: responseData.location.state,
            isFinish: true
         });
     }).done();
    }).done();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) It seems you are using `city` and `state` as passProps and not going to refresh the currentView, so maybe you should use them as variables of the current component.

2) You can simply use a variable to record the state of fetching. Like set `_finish = 0`, when `city` is fetched, `_finish = _finish + 1`, and validate whether _finish equals 2. When `state` is fetched, do the same validate.

```
fetch(...){
   // if _finish is equals 2, navigator push.
}
```

3) Or you can do it without extra variable:

```
fetch(...){
   if (this._city && this._state){
      // navigator push
   }
}
```